# wordpress permalinks error 404

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

i am new to word-press, i have made my own theme in wordpress but the problem that i am facing is the permalinks which are not working and showing me error 404

when my permalinks settings are at default it gives
"The requested URL /wordpress/wordpress/about/ was not found on this server."

else if any other it gives 
"Page not found. Perhaps try searching?"

and with this the Post URL in the address bar is

localhost/wordpress/wordpress/about/%E2%80%9Dhttp:/localhost/wordpress/wordpress/2014/07/23/added-second-post/

i have searched a lot on Google searched for different forums but no such help that could be useful kindly help me in solving this issue,

Comment: does the page about exist in your pages list?

Comment: Yes @David about page exists,

Comment: And you can view it using the view page button in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings/permalinks` then enable/check values by default.
Had the same problem a while ago. This worked for me.